# How to make inactive parts or views (Eclipse RCP 4) "closable with X-Button"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm newbie in Eclipse RCP so please help me with my problem.
I'm currently following this tutorial:
https://sites.google.com/site/tyroprogramming/java/rcp/text-editor/multiple-tabs
and everything works, but I want to know, how can I make all, even inactive Parts so closable, that they have "X"-Button.

Example (X-Button for active Part):
[image: Example (X-Button for active Part)]

It's not the problem for Tabs (setUnselectedCloseVisible), but how to make this for Views and Parts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `swt-unselected-close-visible` in the CSS for your `MPartStack` to set the unselected close value:

```css
.MPartStack 
{
    swt-unselected-close-visible: true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know that tip...and CSS-styling in RCP at all...But I try to find something in "this direction".

Comment: It's strange, but I can't find a good tutorial for CSS for RPC. Maybe you can help me with tipps or domething else. I found this: [link](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/08/18/eclipse-e4-css/), but the part "point="org.eclipse.e4.workbench.parts"" is incorrect (Unknown extension point: org.eclipse.e4.workbench).

Did i understand correctly, that all, what I need:
1) create the folder css with css-file
2) add extension "org.eclipse.core.runtime.products" with property applicationCSS in plugin.xml

Comment: The Vogella tutorials are usually very reliable but that one is rather out of date - this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html is more current. Yes, you just need applicationCSS and the CSS folder.